# alignment of background in internet explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer

i am working on my website http://bookmyshirt.co.cc/help/index.html but its background is not align in internet explorer but it is working fine in firefox.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a DocType.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

I also had a look at your styles. If you replace the styles on #maincontainer:

```
left: -480px;
margin-left: 50%;
position: relative
```

with

```
margin:0 auto;
width: 960px;
```

Everything should line up. If it doesn't, use IE's [developer toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359) to trace the styles. Much like Firebug.

Edit: 
Please note, you must set a width on the element, otherwise **margin:0 auto** won't have any effect.

Comment: Pleasure man. If you feel that this is the correct answer, don't forget to mark it for other people searching for the same thing.